# How can I deploy table or view from SQL to AX

Tags: sql, ax

**How can I deploy table or view from SQL to AX.**

Answer (score 1):

There is a process of database synchronization and during this process the Axapta tables are deploying to SQL Server.

But it is impossible to make a reverse process automatically - deploy a table from MS SQL to Axapta.

Answer (score 1):

Tables and views which are created in AX are deployed to SQL but deployment from SQL to AX is not possible.